# Outlook iCal does not work?

Tags: activities

When an activity is assigned to a user and an email is sent to the assignee with the calendar appointment, the ical is attached. However, when I open the file in Outlook 2013, it says "Meeting cannot be found in the calendar." I'm unable to save/add the meeting date into my calendar. Is there a way to resolve this?

I've also tried the activity iCal module, and I haven't been able to find a solution to add activities to Outlook effectively.

Comment: I'd suggest stripping identifiable information out of the iCal file created and posting it as a code snippet here or on https://gist.github.com, or even posting your report as an issue on https://issues.civicrm.org - then update your question here with a link.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I created an issue here that displays the code snippet: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is resolved. After researching prior problems with icals, I found this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084236/icalendar-does-not-create-an-event-for-organizer

By changing the METHOD: REQUEST to METHOD: PUBLISH in templates/CRM/Activity/Calendar - Outlook users are essentially inviting themselves to their events (and the possibility to including others who are not Civi users).

Note: However, it looks like the notes aren't being pulled into the ical, and I'm not sure if this should occur or not.

Answer (score 0):

The stack exchange thread quoted above also says that if you change METHOD:REQUEST to METHOD:PUBLISH you will get duplicates if you get an update. Also [Dave points out](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16794?focusedCommentId=76125&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-76125) in the CiviCRM issue that was opened that this change breaks the ical standard (which specifies that [you cannot post attendees if the method is publish](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#section-3.2.1)).

This seems like an Outlook bug, so trying to fix it in CiviCRM might not be the best option. And, for Outlook 2007 at least, [there appears to be a fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940403/a-new-meeting-request-is-not-saved-to-your-calendar-folder-after-you-c).